# Why can SELECT see updated row before commit?

Tags: sql-server, transaction

If I run this without a commit statement...

```
begin transaction

update dateranges set DateRangeTypeId = 1 where DateRangeId = 154
```

In another tab of Management Studio, I can select the range with Id 154 and it shows the old value for the type column.

Why doesn't the SELECT block on the updated row?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming the second SSMS window is using the default `READ_COMMITTED` isolation level, you will see the before value instead of being blocked by the uncommitted transaction if the database has the `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT` setting turned on.

```
SELECT name, snapshot_isolation_state_desc
FROM sys.databases
ORDER BY name;
```

The `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT` database setting uses row versioning instead of locking for read consistency so writers don't block readers and visa-versa.

Comment: I tried something similar. It says 'OFF'.

Comment: @IanWarburton, what is the isolation level returned when you execute `DBCC USEROPTIONS;` in the second query window?

Comment: Aha.. there it says 'read committed snapshot'. But I didn't turn it on. Is it the default now?

Comment: @IanWarburton, the default hasn't changed. I can't say how the option may have been changed from the default.